# My nodejs code is being skipped on a Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a node cloud function on GCP, which is working relatively fine, i even have a global logger and logs just to track the workflow, but now i'm having some strange issues with some calls to the cloud function.

```
async function updateCompletedRunInDB(runId, runObject, shouldChargeOrganization) {
log.info(runId + " - starting to update models");

const now = Date.now();

let run;
let chargeableMins;
let outputFileEntry, logFileEntry;

const runQuery = {
 _id: runId,
};

// we load the run from the run model
run = await procLoadRun(runId);
```

and fucntion procLoadRun is something like this...

```
async function procLoadRun(runId) {
try {
 run = await loadRun(runId);
 } catch (err) {
  log.error(err);
  log.error("couldn't be loaded");
 }
  return run;
}
```

where loadRun is a query to mongodb that returns a specific run.

now on the gcp console i have the following (normal case scenario)
[image]

but sometimes i'm getting this one
[image]

Looks like my code is being skipped since procLoadRun is not being called, any ideas or suggestion would be appreciated.

my guess is something related to gcp? the cloud function is on nodejs10 with 1Gib memory

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your function work as expected? I mean, even if y ou don't see log trace, does the function do what it should?

Comment: yes, in normal situations the code always work, but I think when there are multiple requests the code is just skipped, (it's a mongo query and I do a connection to the DB on the index.js)

Comment: My question about the correct behavior of your function is because I suspect issue about the logs (there are currently patch fixing on the logs management in Cloud Function for Python and Node runtime!)